# Salesforce administration questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm thinking about a question along the lines of "how do you administer x in Salesforce?" or "what tools/tips do you recommend for administering x in Salesforce?" but worry they are too generic and dynamic.  Since Salesforce has 3 updates a year and the AppExchange is so active should questions like these be avoided?  If not, what would be the best way to handle it?

Comment: Just ask them - if the community has a problem with it, they'll let you know. :) (It's easier to deal with specific questions than to talk about exclusively theoretical issues.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completely open ended questions aren't the best, but I think with the majority it would be relatively easy to narrow down the scope a little.

For example, instead of "How do I administer territory management?" it may be better to ask "is there a good tutorial on territory management and a list of best practices?". Even though there's still no one correct answer, it's a lot less likely to result in too many different answers and extended discussion!

Comment: Part of my worry is that other users will see the way these questions are asked (in the post title) and the cycle will continue. Therefore, should we ask the OP to re-phrase the questions once it narrowed/answered?

Comment: You can ask, but once you've earned some rep you can just edit the post yourself. I quite regularly re-title posts and add actual questions (where missing) to question bodies.